# docker-compose deployment configuration for Circle CI

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, circleci-2.0

I am using Circle CI to deploy a microservice to a Digital Ocean droplet and had a few questions about whether my approach is the right one.

My microservice is built using `docker-compose`, and therefore requires a docker-compose.yml file to pull, start the images that constitute it.

In a nutshell, my deployment approach would be:

1. Merge branch to master will kick off a CircleCI build
2. CircleCI will run unit tests
3. Upon all tests passing, `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose` push to Docker Hub
4. Stop all running images of that service on remote server.
5. Remove dangling images, and local networks.
6. Download the relevant `docker-compose.yml`, `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.env` files.
7. Pull using `docker-compose pull`
8. Start images using `docker-compose up`

I am using this configuration in CircleCI:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: "circleci/node:10.16.0"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Update to latest npm version
          command: "sudo npm install -g npm@latest"
      - restore_cache: 
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: npm install
      - run:
          name: Install `docker-compose`
          command: |
            curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.19.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > ~/docker-compose
            chmod +x ~/docker-compose
            sudo mv ~/docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
      - setup_remote_docker:
          docker_layer_caching: false 
      - run:
          name: Build using `docker-compose`
          command: |
            docker-compose build
      - run:
          name: Login for Docker Hub
          command: | 
            echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login --username $DOCKER_USERNAME --password-stdin
      - run:
          name: Push to Docker Hub
          command: |
            docker-compose push
      - run: ssh-keyscan $DIGITALOCEAN_HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - fo:of:fe:ef:af
      - run:
          name: Remove currently running containers 
          command: |
            ssh root@$DIGITALOCEAN_HOST ./deploy_image.sh
```

I am planning on creating a bash script to handle steps `4` to `8` from my list above.
Is it a good idea to have a script take care of the Docker steps?
Or is there a better way to have a more "native" CircleCI configuration?

Comment: Hi @frishi, I'd love to see your bash script for this process. :) Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/rishighan/posts-service/blob/master/scripts/deploy/deploy.sh

Look at the circleci config to see how this script is invoked. Hope it helps!